# Can you recommend source code or a way to work with measurement related data?

Tags: c#, .net, measurement, units-of-measurement

Do you know any source code or a lightweight solution that covers all the related features (like converting meter to inches etc.) to work with length and weight measurement types for Imperial and Metric systems for C#?

Is there any built in classes for this purpose in .net library?

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already (I'm guessing you have), check out these related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/units-of-measurement+c%23

Answer (score 0):

I have started developing an open-source units-of-measurement library in C#, suitably named csunits. Please have a look at the csunits website on Github, https://github.com/cureos/csunits. Would this fit your needs?